# Apply PrettyPhoto for all images

Tags: jquery, html, image, prettyphoto

I have an HTML template that comes with PrettyPhoto, but I do not know js/jquery. I want to apply prettyphoto for all the images in my website. jquery-prettyphoto.js is included in all the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
</script>
```

“Just add `rel=”prettyPhoto”` to the link you want prettyPhoto to be enabled on.”

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply any class or rel attribute to the image.
And may be something like below will be added on top.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
</script>
```

If you can post any of your one page it will be more clear.